# Lazarus MySQL connect failed

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, pascal, lazarus

i have normal local server running with MySQL , PHP ,...
I tried to write a Lazarus programm to enter stuff in the SQL.
I can access from every computer in my network the PHPMyAdmin page under 
http://192.168.1.119:8888/phpmyadmin/

So my Lazarus procedure to connect looks like:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   MySQLConnection1.HostName := '192.168.1.119:8888';
   MySQLConnection1.UserName := 'root';
   MySQLConnection1.Password := 'root';
   MySQLConnection1.DatabaseName := 'mysql'; 
   MySQLConnection1.Open;
```

When I press now the Button I get:

Cannot load default mysql libary (libmysql.dll or libmysql.dll)

When I download the libmysql.dll the i get the message that 5.6 is expected but 6.1 found.
When I try to add the 5.6 i get the some error message with cannot load default....

regards Tim

Comment: "i get the some error message"  Well, what exactly does the message say.  You can see your screen, we readers can't.

Comment: are you sure the port is not a different property, or via the generic properties dialog (where you can set key=value pairs?) check wiki, I don't know mysql so good.  And make sure that selected connection type and dll version match

Comment: I mean the same error as I alread described above. With the missing libmysql.dll

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the first problem, my windows missed some files.
But anyway, my programm dont want to connect.
When i built a small php script, the conection is just fine, but my lazarus programm is not able to connect. On the first picture you see my lazarus programm with the error. In the second picture you see my php code.

regards Tim

[lazarus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74QX2.png)

[php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28lS1.png)